# In Java how to easily get the value of a nested key from a JSON String / Object

Tags: java, json

I am using Java.
I have a string that I have converted to a JSON Object.
I want to extract the value of one of the Keys.
At the moment I am using this code:

```
String imageId = myJsonObject.getJSONObject("meta")
                             .getJSONObject("verification")
                             .getJSONObject("derivedData")
                             .getJSONArray("images")
                             .getJSONObject(0)
                             .getString("imageID");
```

This code works ***but surely there must be an easier way***. In javascript I could access the value simply by writing this:

```
myJsonObject.meta.verification.derivedData.images[0].imageId
```

Comment: There is, if you use more advanced methods of parsing. For example: https://javahai.blogspot.com/2016/03/create-java-object-from-json-string.html

Comment: You can also go with the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) question.

Comment: What json library do you use? Jackson, gson, etc?

Comment: Hope this can help: https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath

Answer (score 3):

You may need to install library such as [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to help you select values from a JSON object

An [example](https://www.testingexcellence.com/how-to-parse-json-in-java/) to help understand better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use external library [Gson](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-string-to-jsonobject)

```
 Gson gson=new Gson();
/*You can convert to your DTO as well */
 Map<Object,Object> map = gson.from(myJsonObject,Map.class);
```

Other way is using objectmapper [example](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) of fasterxml.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
    /*You can convert to your DTO as well */
objectMapper.readValue(data, Map.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try JsonNode by below step

```
 String imageId= jsonNode.
 findPath("meta")
.findPath("verification")
.findPath("derivedData")
.findPath("images")
.get (0).findPath ("imageID").asText ();
```

Comment: or you can directly write below code  String imageId = jsonNode.findPath ("images").get (0).findPath ("imageID").asText ();

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'Java API for JSON Binding' JSON-B instead of JSON-P. Using JSON-B you can serialize and deserialize between Java objects and data streams and access values of objects POJO style (similar to what you expect).

API details can be found [here](http:////https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/)

A quick start tutorial can be found [here](https://www.javaindeed.com/getting-started-with-json-b/) and at many website only google search away..

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small class for this purpose which can basically get value from json using a path only used google.gson

https://github.com/izeryab/JsonParser

Here is how to use this for getting nested value from json:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\"data\":[{\"stuff\":[\n" + "    {    \"onetype\":[\n"
                + "        {\"id\":1,\"name\":\"John Doe\"},\n" + "        {\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Don Joeh\"}\n"
                + "    ]},\n" + "    {\"othertype\":[\n" + "        {\"id\":2,\"company\":\"ACME\"}\n" + "    ]}]\n"
                + "},{\"otherstuff\":[\n" + "    {\"thing\":\n" + "        [[1,42],[2,2]]\n" + "    }]\n" + "}]}";

        String name = JsonUtil.getJsonElementFromJsonStringUsingPath("data>0>stuff>0>onetype>0>name", json, ">").getAsString();
        int id= JsonUtil.getJsonElementFromJsonStringUsingPath("data>0>stuff>0>onetype>0>id",json,">").getAsInt();
        
        System.out.println("id : "+id);
        System.out.println("name : "+name);
    }

}
```

Corresponding JAVA DOCS:
https://izeryab.github.io/JsonParser/JsonUtil.html

Answer (score -2):

You can use GSon, I've used it before (see below)

```
// Convert to a JSON object to print data
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
    JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.

    JsonArray jsonDataArray = rootobj.getAsJsonArray("data");
    JsonPrimitive totalJson = rootobj.getAsJsonPrimitive("total");
    JsonPrimitive nextJson = rootobj.getAsJsonPrimitive("next");
```

Comment: "*... but surely there must be an easier way*" can you explain what makes things easier here comparing to code from question?